# Referenced JS File does not let HTML pages get more information than first constant

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a js file for multiple HTML files to reference from for various, relatively quickly changing info, That way I don't need to open all of the HTML pages to locate what I'm looking for in each one. As far as I'm aware my code looks fine, but the only thing that leaves me with text is the "Template" id, unless it's written in an HTML file, then I can utilize them all. I am a noob when it comes to some of these things...

```
class Price{
    constructor(price){
        this.price = price;
    }
}

const Template = new Price("0");
document.getElementById("Template").innerHTML = Template.price;

const DD = new Price("1");
document.getElementById("DD").innerHTML = DD.price;

const PrintDD = new Price("2");
document.getElementById("PrintDD").innerHTML = PrintDD.price;

const FFFF = new Price("3");
document.getElementById("FFFF").innerHTML = FFFF.price;

const TTT = new Price("4");
document.getElementById("TTT").innerHTML = TTT.price;
```

I wouldn't be surprised if I overcomplicated the coding, but I've been scouring for a solution in an attempt to fix the problem.

Comment: I frankly don't understand your problem and the issue you're facing :\ Any errors in console? What's actually the problem here? Pages? what pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, the problem is, if your code is in a page with no element with `id="Template"` then your code will fail with an exception at

```
document.getElementById("Template").innerHTML = Template.price;
```

This is because `document.getElementById("Template")` returns `null` and you can't assign a property (`.innerHTML` in your case) to `null` - so the rest of the code won't run after the `Uncaught TypeError` error is thrown

You could do this

```
class Price{
    constructor(price){
        this.price = price;
    }
    assignToId(id) {
        const element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element) {
            element.innerHTML = this.price;
        }
    }
}

const Template = new Price("0");
Template.assignToId("Template");

const DD = new Price("1");
DD.assignToId("DD");

const PrintDD = new Price("2");
PrintDD.assignToId("PrintDD");

const FFFF = new Price("3");
FFFF.assignToId("FFFF");

const TTT = new Price("4");
TTT.assignToId("TTT");
```

Or even

```
class Price{
    constructor(price, id){
        this.price = price;
        const element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element) {
            element.innerHTML = price;
        }
    }
}

const Template = new Price("0", "Template");
const DD = new Price("1", "DD");
const PrintDD = new Price("2", "PrintDD");
const FFFF = new Price("3", "FFFF");
const TTT = new Price("4", "TTT");
```

However, unless you're using the `class Price` for some other purpose that you haven't shown, the simplest code would be

```
function price(price, id) {
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element) {
        element.innerHTML = price;
    }
}

price("0", "Template");
price("1", "DD");
price("2", "PrintDD");
price("3", "FFFF");
price("4", "TTT");
```

Comment: I would've named `assign` as `assignTo`, clarifies the intent better. Good suggestions, though.

Comment: @RaviKThapliyal - good suggestion - `assignToId` even better ... also could make `assignTo` assign to a `querySelector`, then it wouldn't be limited to id's